# Does using compare on a nil NSNumber always return NSOrderedSame?

Tags: objective-c, compare, nsnumber

```
NSNumber *badNum = 0;
NSNumber *goodNum = @42;
if ([badNum compare:goodNum] == NSOrderedAscending)
    // ...
```

Given the above snippet, where `badNum` is effectively `nil`, **is the `if` statement guaranteed to never be entered?**

Essentially, I want to know if I must do a `nil` check every time I use `-[NSNumber compare:]`, so another question is **will I need to use the following code to make sure compare always works as it appears?**

```
if (badNum && goodNum && [badNum compare:goodNum] == NSOrderedAscending)
    // ...
```

Comment: The logic you need is up to you. You may or may not need to check whether the values are `nil` or not depending on how you wish to treat the `nil` values.

Comment: @rmaddy can you provide examples when messaging `compare:` to a `nil` `NSNumber*` is beneficial?

Comment: If you are sorting the numbers, do you want `nil` values to appear at the beginning of the sort, the end of the sort, or be ignored completely? Your answer to that affects how that `if` statement needs to be written. It's up to you and the needs of your app.

Comment: Related: [Pointer from integer without a cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14610575)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed, as long as Apple does not change `NSOrderedSame`, which is currently defined as zero:

```
enum {
   NSOrderedAscending     = -1,
   NSOrderedSame,      // == 0
   NSOrderedDescending // == 1
};
```

The reason you appear to get `NSOrderedSame` when sending `compare:` message to `nil` is that Objective-C supplies the default value for the return type when the target is `nil`. Since `NSOrderedSame` is `0`, the default value, you are guaranteed to get it when `badNum` is `nil`.

Comment: So I must always do a `nil` check? Man... :/